# wix heat remove namespace using xsl file

Tags: xml, xslt, wix, wix3.6, wix3.7

here is my pre-build script:

```
"%WIX%\bin\heat.exe" dir "$(SolutionDir)Export\Release\SkyCam\Config" -t   "$(SolutionDir)IQStudioInstaller\SimulatorIgnore.xsl" -dr Simulator -srd -cg SimulatorComponentGroup -var var.SimulatorSourcePath -ag -sreg -out "$(SolutionDir)IQStudioInstaller\IQStudioSimulatorDir.wxs"
```

here is my *.xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">


  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space  elements="*"/>
  <!-- identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="wix:Component">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <RemoveFolder Id="{@Id}" On="uninstall" />
      <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the problem i have is the **xlmns** attribute added which is added to my  and  :

**xmlns="" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"**

why this being added and how can i remove it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="Simulator" />
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="SimulatorComponentGroup">
            <Component Id="cmpCAB8CD4B3E3F5DE9BD27E4BE2C6D4ED5" Directory="Simulator" Guid="*">
                <RemoveFolder Id="cmpCAB8CD4B3E3F5DE9BD27E4BE2C6D4ED5" On="uninstall" **xmlns="" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"** />
                <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes" xmlns="" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" />
                <File Id="fil763F3807501181AEBB3384E197DA1B60" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SimulatorSourcePath)\aeStatGridWeights.txt" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp9FA0A11B61A218ED2C433E82749C7264" Directory="Simulator" Guid="*">
                <RemoveFolder Id="cmp9FA0A11B61A218ED2C433E82749C7264" On="uninstall" **xmlns="" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"** />
                <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes" xmlns="" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" />
                <File Id="fil52CCB4416F79DAB20B21723321A693FD" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SimulatorSourcePath)\afStatGridWeights.txt" />
            </Component>
```

**update:**

I edit my *.xsl file like Tim suggested and it fixed one of the problems

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space  elements="*"/>
  <!-- identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="wix:Component">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <RemoveFolder Id="{@Id}" On="uninstall" />
      <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output now is:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="Simulator" />
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="SimulatorComponentGroup">
            <Component Id="cmpCAB8CD4B3E3F5DE9BD27E4BE2C6D4ED5" Directory="Simulator" Guid="*">
                <wix:RemoveFolder Id="cmpCAB8CD4B3E3F5DE9BD27E4BE2C6D4ED5" On="uninstall" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" />
                <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" />
                <File Id="fil763F3807501181AEBB3384E197DA1B60" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SimulatorSourcePath)\aeStatGridWeights.txt" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp9FA0A11B61A218ED2C433E82749C7264" Directory="Simulator" Guid="*">
                <wix:RemoveFolder Id="cmp9FA0A11B61A218ED2C433E82749C7264" On="uninstall" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" />
                <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" />
                <File Id="fil52CCB4416F79DAB20B21723321A693FD" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SimulatorSourcePath)\afStatGridWeights.txt" />
            </Component>
```

so the `xmlns=""` is gone!
however it didn't solve the `xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"`

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to remove the wix namespace altogether from your output, or just the redundant (and harmless) prefixes and their bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with these lines

```
  <RemoveFolder Id="{@Id}" On="uninstall" />
  <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes" />
```

You are outputting elements in NO namespace, but for your Wix file, they need to go in the "http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" namespace.

You can easily fix this by specifying the relevant namespace prefix for the elements

```
  <wix:RemoveFolder Id="{@Id}" On="uninstall" />
  <wix:RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes" />
```

Alternatively, you can add the wix namespace as the default namespace to the XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
```

That way elements with no namespace prefixes will actually be part of the default namespace.

Comment: I am not sure you can do much about that. Although it looks odd, semantically the result is correct though, and it should be happily parsed by Wix.